# Run JS function on .load() content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called timepicker which is usually called by using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

But I have been unable to make it work on content that is displayed using `jQuery .load()`.

I have tried several methods including using the below but nothing happens?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $parent = $('#small_container');
        var time = $parent.find('#timepicker');
        time.timepicker();
});
```

The `#small_container` is the ID of the DIV that the content is loaded into and the `#timepicker` is the id of the input that should call the function when it is clicked on.

Have I added it to the correct place in the callback?

```
$('.edit_job').on("click", function(){
    var week_start = $('input[name=week_start]').val();
    var job_id_del= $('input[name=job_id]').val();
    var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();
    $('#small_container').load('ajax/edit_weekly_job_load.php?job_id='+job_id_del+'&week_start='+week_start+"&user="+user_id);
    $('#timepicker').timepicker();
    $('#small_container').on("click", '#edit_job_submit', function(){
          jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax/edit_weekly_job_ajax.php",
              dataType: "json",
              data: $('#edit_job_form').serialize(),
              success: function(response){
                  if(response.success === 'success'){
                    window.opener.$("#diary").load("ajax/diary_weekly_load.php?week_start="+week_start+"&user="+user_id);
                    window.close();
                }
              },
        });//end ajax
    });//save_job_edit_submit
});//end edit job
```

Comment: Can you elaborate _The `#small_container` is the ID of the DIV that the content is loaded into and the `#timepicker`_

Comment: If you are adding the element to the dom with the `.load` then you should add the `.timepicker()` in the callback function.

Comment: Where is your load function? Should be able to call `$('#timepicker').timepicker();` as part of the load function.

Comment: You should call `$('#timepicker').timepicker()` after the dynamic content loaded, so in the callback of your ajax `.load()`

Comment: @Satpal #small_container is the element that the the content using.load() is loaded into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is loaded asynchronously to the element #small_container. The timepicker function is gets called before the content is actually loaded. Try to call the function in the callback of load() method:
$('#small_container').load('ajax/edit_weekly_job_load.php?job_id='+job_id_del+'&week_start='+week_start+"&user="+user_id ,function(){
 $('#timepicker').timepicker();
} );

Also validate that element #timepicker is actually appended to the element #small_container.

Comment: thanks but it is a different plugin (didn't realise there were more than one with the same name).  The one I am using is https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Comment: Please check the following dependencies are present as per the link you shared:
jQuery (tested with version up to 1.9.0)
jQuery UI Core (included in jquery-ui-x.x.x.custom.min.js, tested with version 1.10.0)
jQuery UI Position utility (optional for special position of the dialog)
jQuery UI Theme.css (included in jquery-ui-x.x.x.custom.css)
jquery.ui.timepicker.js
jquery.ui.timepicker.css

Comment: all of the dependencies are there, I have it working on another page that has no dynamic content using the same files